# Jparepository not deleting

Tags: java, jpa, repository

Html

```
            <form th:action="@{/deleteCartItem(id=${produkt.product.id})}" th:object="${produkty}" method="post">
                <div class="text-right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn-sm btn-danger" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

Cart controller

```
@GetMapping("/kosik")
public String kosik(Principal principal,Model model){
    User user = userServices.findByEmail(principal.getName());
    Cart cart = cartServices.findCartByUser(user);
    model.addAttribute("produkty",cartItemServices.findAllCartItems(cart));
    model.addAttribute("cart",cartServices.findCartByUser(user));
    model.addAttribute("user",user);
    return "cart";
}
```

Delete method

```
@PostMapping("/deleteCartItem")
public String deleteCartItem(@ModelAttribute CartItem cartItem){
    cartItemServices.deleteCartItem(cartItem.getCartItemId());
    return "redirect:/kosik";
}
```

Service

```
public void deleteCartItem(Integer id){
        cartItemRepository.deleteById(id);
    }
```

CartItem Entity

```
@Entity
public class CartItem {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer cartItemId;
    @NotNull
    @Max(11)
    private int quantity;
    private double price;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "cart_id")
    private Cart cart;
```

Getting cartitem id works, but i cant delete cartItem.. I also tryied delete it not by id, but delete cartItem instantly..

Comment: share the CartItem  entity

Answer (score 1):

Since your entity don't have id field as primary key. It's not working.

Define the below method in CartItemRepository and use it to delete the Object.

```
Long deleteByCartItemId(Long id);
```

Or rename the cartItemId field as id.

Comment: I even changed all Entities ids(cartitem_id,product_id) just to id, but  any of those methods are not working.. Also repository.delete is not working..